# Can a quantum computer implement a classical one?

Tags: quantum-computer, computer

The normal question about this topic would be: Can a classical computer implement a quantum computer? But now I wonder the exact opposite: can a quantum computer implement a classical one? Can we say that classical computation is a subset of quantum computing?

Comment: Isn't the question whether one class of computer can *tractably* implement the other? I believe that a classical computer can simulate a quantum computer, but the complexity just gets bad very rapidly in the worst cases.

Comment: Your current computer is using tons of qubits without taking advantage of any of the special quantum features.

Answer (score 4):

**Yes**, it is perfectly possible to run a quantum computer as a classical one, simply by keeping all the qubits in 0 or 1 and deciding not to use the capability to place them on superpositions of those states or entangle them to each other.

To be a bit more precise, the computation complexity class BQP (of problems that can be efficiently solved in a quantum computer) contains as a subset the class BPP (of problems that can be efficiently solved in a classical computer, if you allow for a finite probability of success) which itself contains the class P (of problems that can be efficiently solved in a classical computer). The Wikipedia pages for those complexity classes have more detail on those inclusions.

Comment: I think OP may be referring to the issue where you can only use reversible gates, e.g. fully quantum computers cannot use AND gates.

Comment: @knzhou [Reversible computing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reversible_computing) is Turing complete and can be happily implemented in quantum computers. (In more detail: quantum computers cannot implement 'standard' (lossy) AND gates, but they have no problem with the reversible-computing equivalent $(x,y,z)\mapsto (x,y,z\oplus(x\otimes y))$.)